Passing the result of a DB find() with props, to a react component
After reading data from a MongoDB Atlas database (in a Next.js app), using a server component. I want to pass the result (as props) to a client component (to provide some interactivity in the user interface); but this is the point where things go wrong.
Here is the (relevant) code for my Next.js server component:
(with some comments included)
import connectDB from "../../configDB";
import mongoose from "mongoose";


export default async function GetShops() {
  await connectDB()

  const {Schema} = mongoose;

  const restoSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    ...
    zipCode: String
  });

  const MyModel = mongoose.model('mycollection', restoSchema);

  const results = await MyModel.find({})

  console.log("find-result : "+results.length)
  console.log("find-result : "+results[0].name)
  console.log("find-result : "+results[1].name)
  // The console.log above are working as expected.
  // Up to here all is GOOD !

  return (
    <ShowShops shops={results} /> // This is not working !!
  )
} /* End of GetShops */

Here is the relevant code for the client component:
'use client';

import mongoose from "mongoose";
.....

const {Schema} = mongoose;

const restoSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  ...
  zipCode: String
});

export default function ShowShops({shops}:{shops:(typeof restoSchema)[]}) {
  .....
  .....

  return (
    <>
    .....
    </>
  )
} /* End of ShowShops */

The parameter-passing through props is obviously using a wrong syntax.
Searching the net I have tried a few variations on the code, but for the time being it all fails.
I hope someone can put me on the proper track by providing some relevant hints.

You misunderstood the typeof keyword, it only infers javascript primitive types (in your case it'll just return object). So you need to introduce a custom TS type, i.e.:
interface MyCustomType {
    name: string;
    ...
    zipCode: number;
}

const restoSchema = new Schema<MyCustomType>({ ... });

export default function ShowShops({ shops: Schema<MyCustomType>[] }) {
   ...
}


I am now trying to work from your suggestion, but still with no success. How exactly do you complete the line "const restoSchema = new Schema ....???" And are you sure about the syntax you use for "export default function ShowShops ..... ???"

Also, it seems your code never uses restoSchema. So I am not sure how to interpret it.

Yeah sorry about the syntax, might be slightly off.. all I wanted to say is you should introduxe your own custom type instead of using typeof.

Anyway that answer helped me quite a bit.
